# Two Ajax dynamically created elements can't recognize each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Dear Stack Overflow community,

I have been trying to develop a table creator that creates two tables dynamically when a button is clicked. This has worked... Well it hasn't at least for now.

Right now I am generating a `<p>` element with class heading and a `<div>` element with class content. When `p` is clicked, content is slideToogled.

I have tried using `on()` with jQuery or attaching any function to the

element but it doesn't seem to work. Also `.hide()` doesn't work on content which is extremely annoying. Can anyone give me some advice as to how to approach this please?

On seems to work for content I hard written with HTML, but it doesn't on AJAX generated code appended to the div.

Here are the related snippets of code:
Ajax:

```
function submition() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'phpQueries.php?q=getQueryBuilder&schools=' + mySchools.toString()+ '&depts=' + myDeps.toString() + '&lvls=' + myLevs.toString() + '&srcs='+mySrc.toString() + '&codes='+myCodes.toString(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#dump_here").append(data);
            }
        });
```

jquery:

```
$(".heading").on("click", function() {
                alert("Hello World");
                $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
          });
```

PHP:

```
echo '<p class="heading">See/Hide Comments</p> ';
    echo '<div class="content">I am I am I am.... Superman!</div>';
```

Kind Regards,
Gempio

Comment: Normally it does. Can you should your code?

Comment: The code has been updated.

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Which parts are the dynamic parts? Is `.heading` dynamic? Where (and when) are you attaching the `click` handler? The `.on()` function should be attached to a parent element that actually exists at the time the handler is attached and should use a selector to filter events that bubble up from dynamically generated elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This because (if I understand correctly) you create a `<p>` tag with the class `heading` after you assign the click event handler.

What you want to do is [delegate your events](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to a container that contains your `<p>` tag. So, let's assume this is your structure:

```
<div id="dump_here"></div>
```

You then do this in your JavaScript:

```
$("#dump_here").on("click", ".heading", function () {
    ....
```

This way you assign an event handler to the parent container which already exists, and the event will bubble up once you click on your paragraph. Now you can dynamically add new elements to your HTML within that container and your event handlers will still work.

Why is that? Because you can't assign event handlers to elements that don't exist.

When you do this:

```
$(".something").click(...)
```

You don't tell Javascript to do something whenever you click any element with the `something` class on the page, you assign an event handler to every single already-existing `something` on the page. If you create a new element, even if it is the same class, you still need to assign an event handler to it.

A quote from the jQuery documentation:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`

Also David Walsh [wrote a nice article](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) explaining Event Delegation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wonderful answer. I wasn't sure about how to use the on() properly. Now I do. Amazing help!

Answer (score 1):

So let's say, that this is your HTML:

```
<div id="dump_here">
    <!-- contents here are dynamic - these don't exist when the page first loads -->
    <p class="heading">See/Hide Comments</p>
    <div class="content">I am I am I am.... Superman!</div>
    <!-- end of dynamic content -->
</div>
```

Now on doc ready you attach your handler:

```
$(function() {
    // $(".heading").click(//...this won't work, heading doesn't exist on load
    $("#dump_here").on("click",".heading",function() {
        // this will work - the handler is attached to an element that exists on load
        // and will respond to event that bubble up from elements with the class 'heading'
    });

    submition();   // async function that populates your dynamic parts.
});
```

Be sure to read the docs on [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

The important part to understand is this:

```
$(".heading")
```

This returns a collection of jQuery objects that represent DOM elements that have the class of `heading`. If there are no matching elements in the DOM when you execute that line, you will have an empty collection. But jQuery won't complain about this and will still let you chain to that empty collection:

```
$(".heading").on("click", function() { //...
```

What this says is `attach an event handler to all the matching dom elements in my collection that will execute this function when the click event is triggered`. But if your collection is empty, it won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$(".heading").on("click", function() {
    alert("Hello World");
    $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
});
```

to:

```
$(document).on("click", ".heading", function() {
    alert("Hello World");
    $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
});
```

Alternatively you can put the definition of $(".heading").on("click", ...) into your AJAX success callback, but if you have multiple `.heading` elements you'll run into multiple event bindings for elements that were there before the AJAX runs, say if it runs twice and appends 2 tables.  The reason your method didn't work is the element has to exist before the event is bound.  The 1st option I proposed works because the document is where the event is bound, and the last option works because it's in the callback of the AJAX that creates the element, so the element exists at the time it was bound.